# How to quantify the effect of the inputs and the effect of the labels on our regression model?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, gradient-descent, interpretation

Let us imagine in a regression setting where our responses are D dimensional vectors, and so are our inputs. Let's say I train a regression model (e.g, Neural network).

When I update my weights on a single data point, both the inputs and the label will impact the value of the derivatives. For instance, if I have two pairs of input and label, where the inputs are the same but the labels are different, then the effect on the weights will be different and the different will strictly come the difference in the label. Conversely,for inputs that are different but equal labels.

Is there a good way to quantify the contribution of the input vs the label towards my weight updates (e.g, input is responsible for 60% and output for 40%)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for the ratio of $\frac {\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial w}$ and $\frac {\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial w}$?

Comment: I reckon this may be a good way to do so. thanks